# Secure Spring Boot / Vaadin web-interface with rest api

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, vaadin

I made an app with Spring Boot and Vaadin which provides rest functionality for mobile devices.

Currently the api-requests are secured by an Auth-Token and I want to use the security features for the web-interface (Login, etc) from vaadin..

What would you recommend me to do?

How can I set the project up, that api-calls from mobile devices are secured by the Auth-Token and only users use the interface, who are logged in?